# Implementing a math formula in Scheme (DrRacket)

Tags: scheme, racket, map-function

Let me start off by saying that I am a complete novice when it comes to Scheme/Racket. I am trying to implement the following formula:

*α<sub>i</sub> = (3/h)((a<sub>i+1</sub> – a<sub>i</sub>) – (a<sub>i</sub> – a<sub>i-1</sub>))*

Here is how I've defined my function:

```
(define alpha_values (lambda (y_values h n) (...))
```

What I would like it to do is to run the function with a list of `y_values` along with some constant `h` and a number `n`, then compute and return a list of *α* values. `n` will go from *1* to *n-1*, so the first and last element of the list are not going to be iterated upon.

For example, if the list of `y_values` is `'(2 4 6 8)` and `h` is *1* and `n` is *3* then there should be two *α* values returned: one for *i=1* (*y=4*), and one for *i=2* (*y=6*), like so: *3*((6-4)-(4-2)) = 0* and *3*((8-6)-(6-4)) = 0* returns `'(0 0)` for *α*.

Truthfully, I'm lost as to how to even begin to implement this. I thought about using `map` but I don't know if it's possible to skip the first and last element while doing so. I've tried doing so recursively using `car` and `cdr` but I ran into the issue of "losing" an element in the list needed for the calculation when recursively calling the function again without the first element. I would appreciate some insight as to how to approach the implementation of this formula – not an answer, just an idea as to how to get the ball rolling.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whenever you are unsure about how to approach a particular problem, consider breaking it down to smaller tasks that are easier to manage, think about, and implement.

For example, going backwards from the end result, you want to produce a list of alphas, whereby each alpha is created from `h` and an interval `{a_i-1, a_i, a_i+1}`  using the noted formula.

So one small function you can create would be the function, lets call it `compute-alpha`, that takes an *interval* and `h` as arguments, then produces an alpha using the formula. Ie:

```
(define (compute-alpha interval h)
  ...)
```

The body of this function will simply be the formula, and it will behave as follows:

```
> (compute-alpha '(2 4 6) 1)
0
> (compute-alpha '(4 6 8) 1)
0
```

But then you realize that you don't have the intervals (eg. `'(2 4 6)`, `'(4 6 8)` etc) in order to use `compute-alpha`. So next step is to define another small function, lets call it `build-intervals`, that takes `y-values` and `n` as arguments, and produces a list of intervals. Ie:

```
(define (build-intervals y-values n)
  ...)
```

and behaves as follows:

```
> (build-intervals '(2 4 6 8) 3)
'((2 4 6) (4 6 8))
> (build-intervals '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7) 4)
'((1 2 3) (2 3 4) (3 4 5))
```

Now, all that is left is applying `compute-alpha` on every interval produced by `build-intervals`. And this is where `map` shines:

```
(define (alpha-values y-values h n)
  (map (lambda (interval)
         (compute-alpha interval h))
       (build-intervals y-values n)))
```

Then you can have:

```
> (alpha-values '(2 4 6 8) 1 3)
'(0 0)
```

---

Once you implement `build-intervals` and `compute-alpha`, you might notice ways of combining them to reduce `alpha-values` to a single function that iterates `y-values` only once before producing the list of alphas.